# how to calculate distance from two point, point A is user location, and point B is Placepicker.getlatlang()

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-latitude, gmsplacepicker

```
{    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == Place_Picker_Request){
        place_Picket = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
        String nama = String.format("%s",place_Picket.getName());
        _txplaceName.setText("Name : "+nama);
        String address = String.format("%s",place_Picket.getAddress());
        _txplaceAddres.setText("Addres : "+address);
        String latlang = String.format("%s",place_Picket.getLatLng());
        _txplacePhoneNumber.setText("LatLng :"+latlang);

        "I will calculate distance betwen my location with latlang from placepicker"
        "and show in toast"


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"",Toast.Length_short).show();
        String url = String.format("%s",place_Picket.getWebsiteUri());
        _txplaceWebsite.setText("Alamat Website : "+url);


    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: yes, but placepicker just have getlatlang() merthod, how to get just lotitute and longitute from place picker ?? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PlacePicker you get LatLang like

```
final LatLng location = place.getLatLng();
```

and than you can get Latitude and Longitude from the LatLng like

```
double lat = LatLng.latitude;
double lng = LatLng.longitude;
```

see [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) for more.